# Varnish wildcard purge

Tags: varnish

I am using Varnish 3.0.3

Presently I know how to purge single URLs using this VCL:

```
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
  if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
      error 405 "Not allowed";
  }
  return(lookup);
  error 200 "Purged";
}
```

I would like to issue a wildcard purge, such as:

```
PURGE: http://www.mysite.com/images/*
```

Does Varnish support this?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119786/varnish-purge-using-http-and-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using telnet:

```
telnet serverip 6082
purge req.url == "/images/"
```

Comment: Although I would have preferred an HTTP approach, this did work well. Thanks Paul. I wound up using varnishadm instead of telnet because our servers require authentication.

Comment: Hello, please try: varnishadm -T host:6082 purge req.url == "/images/"

Answer (score 0):

The `purge` command was renamed to `ban.url` in Varnish 3.

The correct way would then be

```
ban.url "/images/*"
```

You can connect using `telnet host:port` or `varnishadm -T host:port` (the default port being 6082)